# find in std::list

Tags: c++, stl, stdlist

Hi I am getting compilation error from the following code. I am not able to figure out:

```
g++ stl_list_1.cc
stl_list_1.cc: In function \u2018int main()\u2019:
stl_list_1.cc:16: error: \u2018struct std::_List_iterator<int>\u2019 has no member named \u2018clist\u2019
stl_list_1.cc:19: error: \u2018struct std::_List_iterator<int>\u2019 has no member named \u2018clist\u2019
stl_list_1.cc:25: error: no match for call to \u2018(std::list<std::_List_const_iterator<int>, std::allocator<std::_List_const_iterator<int> > >) (int&)\u2019
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

main()
{
    std::list<int> clist;
    for (int i =0; i<10; i++)
    {
        clist.push_back(i);
    }

    std::list<std::list<int>::const_iterator> list1;

    std::list<int>::iterator itr1;
    itr1 = std::find(clist.begin().clist.end(),1);
    std::list<int>::iterator itr2 ;

    itr2 = std::find(clist.begin().clist.end(),7);

    list1.push_back(itr1);
    list1.push_back(itr2);

    for(int j =0; j< list1.size(); j++)
    {
       int k = *list1[j];
       std::cout << "cvalue " << k <<std::endl;
       j++;
     }
}
```

Thanks
Ruchi

Answer (score 3):

It's a typo, you used a dot instead of a comma:

```
itr1 = std::find(clist.begin().clist.end(),1);
                              ^
```

It should be like this:

```
itr1 = std::find(clist.begin(), clist.end(),1);
```

You made that mistake in both of your calls to `std::find`.

In addition, you are trying to use `operator[]` on a list, which won't work. Instead of:

```
int k = *list1[j];
```

You could use:

```
itr1 = list1.begin();
std::advance(itr1, j);
int k = *itr1;
```

As JohnB mentioned, the above code is inefficient. Isolated, it's the same, but since you are using this inside a loop, it would be better to just use the list iterators to perform the iteration:

```
for(itr1 = list1.begin(); itr1 != list1.end(); ++itr1)
{
   int k = *itr1;
   std::cout << "cvalue " << k <<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Although that advance part at the end is correct, it will be terribly inefficient inside that loop ending up as O(N^2).
Better to use an iterator to step through the list once instead of an index

Comment: @JohnB you're right, I saw the problem isolated. It would be best to just use an iterator, I'll fix that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, please bear in mind that

```
list1[j]
```

does not work because a list has no index operator so you have to iterate over it.

Suggestion: use a `std::vector< int >` instead of a `std::list< int >`.

Answer (score 0):

As other people have noted there's a typo in the `find` calls (`.` instead of `,`).

But also once you get past that `list` doesn't have a `[]` operator so you'll find that part doesn't work right either. You'll need to use iterators to loop over the list in your final loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
int k = *list1[j];
```

That will not compile either.

Maybe something like this might (not checking any safety etc, its a crap way, but just showing)

```
int k = *(find(clist.begin(), clist.end(), j));
```

Also you increment j twice, did you mean this?

```
for(int j =0; j< list1.size(); j++) //here
{
   int k = *list1[j];
   std::cout << "cvalue " << k <<std::endl;
   j++; //and here?
}
```